# Adwhirl disproportionate

Tags: android, adwhirl

I'm using Adwhirl with InMobi and my house ads.

my house ads shares;

A 30%
B 35%
C 35%

but my house ads impressions like that:

A ~160
B ~120
C ~11000(!)

B and C should be approximately the same, but not even close.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these values from the AdWhirl Reporting tab?  Unfortunately, AdWhirl's reporting tab is very inaccurate at times.  I'd suggest ignoring this and instead looking directly at a particular Ad Network's reports.  I know that's not an option for house ads, so those values need to be taken with a grain (or two or three) of salt.